# Is it possible to have two lines of best fit?

Tags: statistics, regression

Could you rig a data set to have two lines of equally good (and best) fit? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible (in mostly silly cases).  For example, suppose you sample the same $x$ value twice and get two experimental $y$ values that differ.  One such case might be getting the points $(0, -1)$ and $(0, 1)$ if we sample $x=0$ twice.  Then, any line passing through the origin has SSE=2 which is the minimum possible.  But of course there are many lines passing through the origin.

The root source of this problem is the fact that the "best-fit-slope", the $\beta$ in the formula here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line is undefined (division by $0$).

Comment: I think I'm missing something here.  If you sample $x=0$ don't you necessarily get a point of the form $(0, y)$, and $(1,1)$ is not of that form?

Comment: If you consider "best fits" with more than 1 independent variable (1 independent variable, $x$ in the above case) then there are more interesting cases when there is not a unique best fit line.

Comment: @MJD, Sorry, I've fixed that (typo on my part)

Comment: So the points are actually points in $n$-space with $n>2$?  I am confused by your use of only two coordinates.

Comment: @MJD, the points live in 2-space.  There is one independent variable (the $x$-value) that we choose and then make a sample.  The sampled time (dependent) is the $y$ value.  Presumably, the experimental observation is subject to some amount of randomness (if you repeat an experiment the results are not 100% identical, usually close though).  Hence the $y$ value can vary even though we sample the same $x$ value.  If, one sampled multiple $x$ values then this problem wouldn't occur.

Comment: In your example, I do not understand why $x=0$ would not be the unique line of best fit.

Comment: @MJD, this is a good point.  I was under the impression that we were finding a "best fit linear function" (of one variable), and $x=0$ is not a function of $x$.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear. If it is about uniqueness, this is a solution.

Consider the linear system
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} x &=b \\
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x \\
 y
\end{array}
\right)
%
&=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
 b_{1} \\
 b_{2} 
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
$$
The least squares solution is defined as
$$
  x_{LS} = 
\left\{
  x \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \colon
\lVert 
  \mathbf{A}x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$

**Least squares minimizers form an affine space**

The least squares minimizers for this problem are the affine space
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\left(
\begin{array}{l}
 b_{1} \\
 0 
\end{array}
\right)}
+
\alpha
\color{red}{
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right)}, \qquad \alpha \in \mathbb{C}
$$
The coloring identifies $\color{blue}{range}$ and $\color{red}{null}$ space components.

Every point in this set generates the minimum value for the total error:
$$
  r^{2} \left( x_{LS} \right) = b_{1}^{*} b_{1}
$$

**Solution of minimum norm**

The norm of the minimizers is
$$
 \lVert x_{LS} \rVert_{2}^{2} = 
 \Bigg\lVert \color{blue}{\left(
\begin{array}{l}
 b_{1} \\
 0 
\end{array}
\right)}
%
  +
%
\alpha
\color{red}{
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right)}
 \Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} = 
%
 \Bigg\lVert \color{blue}{\left(
\begin{array}{l}
 b_{1} \\
 0 
\end{array}
\right)}
 \Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2}
%
  +
%
\bar{\alpha}
 \Bigg\lVert_{2}^{2}
\color{red}{
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right)}
 \Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} 
%
$$

The minimizer of minimum length, $\hat{x}$ is given by $\alpha = 0$, the projection onto $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$. This is also the pseudoinverse solution
$$
 \color{blue}{\hat{x}} = 
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b}.
$$